# Trying to embed an iframe in shopify page template. But the iframe is not loading. Though it is loading perfectly fine elsewhere

Tags: iframe, shopify

Trying to embed an iframe in shopify page template. But the iframe is not loading. Though it is loading perfectly fine elsewhere. Is it allowed to load an iframe in Shopify page template?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue of "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" , you are trying to access data from 'http'. And your shopify site will be in 'https'.